# Is is possible to add a title to scatter.smooth?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I use often  `scatter.smooth` function but I wonder if it is possible to add a `title` or `main` argument directly to this function. I read the description of the function but have not found the possibility. I know that there are other ways to do this but I want to keep this one if possible.

```
d <- data.frame(x = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE), 
                y = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE),
                z = rnorm(500, 20, 4))
mo <- lm(y ~ z, d)
fig <- function(x) {
  scatter.smooth(fitted(x), residuals(x, type = "response"), col = "red")
  abline(0, 0, lty = 2)
  legend("topright", legend = c("loss", "0-0"), lty = c(1, 2))
}
fig(mo)
```

Comment: The function `scatter.smooth()` is available as R-source. It has no parameter for `title` and `main`. IMHO in this aspect the function is similar to `points()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the help page of `scatter.smooth`, you see that the `...` argument is passed on to `plot`. Therefore, you can us any argument that `plot` accepts. Also `main=`.

You can also add a title to any graph using `mtext` which adds text to the figure margins.

So, you can do:

```
fig(mo)
mtext("My title", side=3, line=1)
```

Or modify your `fig` function:

```
fig <- function(x, ...) {
  scatter.smooth(fitted(x), residuals(x, type = "response"), 
    col = "red", ...)
  abline(0, 0, lty = 2)
  legend("topright", legend = c("loss", "0-0"), lty = c(1, 2))
}
fig(mo, main="My title")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `main` to the `smooth` function:

```
scatter.smooth(x, y, ylab = "Yname", xlab = "Xname", main = "Title")
```

It works